# Provide a password protected calendar for each individual user

Tags: firebase, authentication, calendar, icalendar, caldav

I am building a Public Web App (react, typescript, firebase firestore) in which users can manage events of ther groups. A group can have any number of members, which can all log in to the page to see their next events. I want to dynamically create a calendar-file (.ics / ical) for each individual member so they can add it to their personal calendars via CalDAV. **But these files need to be private.** A CalDav app, like Apple Calendar or Google Calendar should provide the login information for firebase, so that only with the right credentials a user can see his calendar.

Is that possible? I'm open for any kind of suggestion no matter what technology, framework or even third-party option.

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than trying to use passwords in the URLs, I would just generate long, unguessable URLs for the calendars that are publicly accessible otherwise.

Comment: Sadly that's not an option because that url could be sniffed. Also we need to log the user into firebase with the credentials provided by the caldav

Comment: "Sniffed" in what sense? You can use `robots.txt` to prohibit crawling and sufficiently large random values are in many cases effectively as secure as a password.

That being said, if you want it to authz to Firebase you'd probably mint a [Firebase custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and put that as the password of an HTTP basic credential.

Comment: good point! I will dig into that :) Thank you!